# Backup Time capsule content for later restore

Tags: backup, restore, time-capsule

I am selling my Time Capsule. I would like to back up its contents so that when I get a new one later, I can restore its contents back. There is a documented way to backup and restore to a new time capsule if you have both the old and new devices available.

How can I backup the contents to a hard drive **so that I can restore it later to a new Time Capsule**? Can I just copy the contents?

Answer (score 1):

1. Install the replacement back up device first.
2. Let the replacement drive finish at least one complete back up.
3. Secure shred the data on the old one.